# The list of votes cast should point to the specific revision the user voted on

Tags: feature-request, voting, revision-history

Let's say I voted on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11227809/why-is-it-faster-to-process-a-sorted-array-than-an-unsorted-array) a year ago.

When I check [the list of votes I cast](https://stackoverflow.com/users/current?tab=votes), I see it in the list, but pointing to the latest revision, not the one on which I voted.

To know what was the state of the post at the time I voted, I need to manually check [the revision history of that question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/11227809/revisions).

I think it would be better if, instead of pointing to the latest revision in  the list of votes I cast, it would point to exactly the revision on which  I voted on (in this case it would be [revision 44](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/11227809/44)).

And doesn't seem hard to implement. Also, if it's the first and only revision, [it'll just show 1 of 1](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/50331205/1).

Comment: @jonrsharpe - [that edit is debatable](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/94565/can-casted-be-the-past-tense-of-cast)

Comment: I fail to see *why* you would need to know what the post looked like when you voted, is there any compelling reason for why this feature would be useful? There are lots of things that are easy to implement but that doesn't mean it's a good idea. The sum of features add complexity on its own.

Comment: @ivarni might be most useful for *downvotes*. If I see a question/answer a year after I downvoted, and it looks good, I might be confused as to why I downvoted, but it might just be due to plenty of revisions that took place in the meantime

Comment: If you try to undo your vote (click on the arrow again) and it's too old to undo you get a message saying when you cast that vote. You can find the revision from the post history based on that. I see your point but I'm not sure it needs a separate feature.

Answer (score 2):

I would advise you to take only the *current state* of a post into account when deciding how to vote on it. Past revision history is irrelevant here. If you go back to a post you've already voted on and feel you should've voted differently, you're always welcome to change your vote as long as the post was edited in the interrim.

Comment: I don't talk about deciding what the vote should be "today", but to see what I voted on "yesterday"

Comment: @Adelin right, and my response leads to the point that since revision history of a post is irrelevant in determining how a post should be voted on, this feature isn't necessary, even if it _is_ trivial to implement.